# Practical Idealist - Moral Perfection

Tags: meaning

My friend told me that 'practical idealist' means 'moral perfection'.

Does "practical idealist" mean "moral perfection"? Is she correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be in a sort, but it's not *always* certain !

"Moral perfection" is & must be above practical considerations, even if these ones are idealized/ing.

In fact "practical idealist" implies *moral perfection* only on practical & concrete field. But this ground level is not all, especially not, for moral perfection which rises above all without compromising with common contingencies where remains - at a lower step - the practical idealist, who is idealistic indeed but only for practical questions or purposes.

Now we have to warn you : your girlfriend is a practical idealist. Beware ! :)